# how does elasticsearch ngrams scoring work?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two documents in my index. One contains field :

```
 name: foo bar
```

and another

```
 name: foo xyz bar xyz foo xyz bar xyz foo xyz bar xyz foo xyz bar
```

I'm using ngrams analyzer like this:

```
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "ngram_analyzer": {
      "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer"
    }
  },
  "tokenizer": {
    "ngram_tokenizer": {
      "type": "ngram",
      "min_gram": 3,
      "max_gram": 3,
      "token_chars": [
        "letter",
        "digit",
        "whitespace"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and when I search for `foo bar` first document gets higher score then second. This is what I want but can anybody explain how does this scoring work? as I know ngram splits them in 3 character length terms and how does it founds out that `foo` and `bar` are in sequence in first document and assigns to it higher score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevance/scoring in Elasticsearch is not the easiest part when you are starting. Score calculation is based on three main parts:

- Term frequency
- Inverse document frequency
- Field-length norm

Shortly:

- the often the term occurs in field, the MORE relevant is
- the often the term occurs in entire index, the LESS relevant is
- the longer the term is, the MORE relevant is

I recommend you to read below materials:

- [What Is Relevance?](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-intro.html)
- [Theory Behind Relevance Scoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html)
- [Controlling Relevance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/controlling-relevance.html) and subpages

But additionally score will depend on type of query you are using. For example for `match` query `foo bar` search term better suits the `foo bar` document than the second one.